# How to convert csv file to json using robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I have been trying to convert csv file to json using robot framework. How u can do file handling in robot framework.

Comment: Show your trials and errors. Don't add the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries for handling csv and json, f.e.:
https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-csvlib/
https://robotframework-thailand.github.io/robotframework-jsonlibrary/JSONLibrary.html
...

So i think there is a way, but effective way in my opinion is to write simple python script to convert file and execute it by `run process` from build in process library and then load JSON file using JSONlibrary.